# Postgres archive_cleanup_command is not recognized

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I put this in my postgresql.conf (line 193):

```
archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup C:\\pg\\archivedir %r'
```

Now, when I am trying to launch my server, I get this error :

```
LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "archive_cleanup_command" in file "c:/pg/postgresql.conf" line 193
FATAL:  configuration file "c:/db_slave/postgresql.conf" contains errors
```

Do you know why the command isn't recognized/

C:\bin\pgsql is in my path and `pg_archivecleanup` can be executed from by cmd.

Last info :

```
pg_ctl --version 

> pg_ctl (PostgreSQL) 9.2.3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`archive_cleanup_command` is a command that you put in the `recovery.conf` file of a standby server.

It's not meant for `postgresql.conf`

See [Archive Recovery Settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/archive-recovery-settings.html) in the docs.